# Android studio crahsing when i tried to add retrofit functionalities, why?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i've been making an app that sends gyroscope and accelerometer info to a pc txt file.
I'm new in coding and app making ect ect. But i need this app made by me to get some experience under my belt doing this kinda stuff.
I've been making this app for 3 days now i believe and now i've gotten to the point of getting info from retrofit and having it displayed on the screen.
The next step being to send data to an web site.
Well i've ran into an problem.

When i added retrofit funcionalities the app always crashes when i try to run it on my phone.
I had to make an new activity where i could receive the txt from retrofit's website, but everytime i try to run the app it crashes. Can't find anything from the console (sence im a newbvie im guessing) so i decided to come here.

I've tried to google answers without luck.

If it helps i've been using YouTube tutorials to get this all setup so i don't really no anything about coding. Be free to assume that i'm making all the beginner mistakes.

If anyone could try and offer help it would be greatly appreciated.
Answer me what i need to send to help me diagnose this problem.

Thanks!

Did a bit of googling, guessing this is the stacktrace

--------- beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.testi, PID: 2622 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testi/com.example.testi.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate() at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate() at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:6800) at com.example.testi.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:56) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95) at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45) at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

p.s sorry for bad english / grammar. Not my 1st language.

Comment: Could you please provide the stacktrace

Comment: Added it into the question. @MuhammadAhmed